# Filtrar palavras contidas no BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vb.net

Preciso filtrar em meu `DataGridView` que tem como o *datasource* um `BindingSource` (`filtro_descricao`).
Preciso buscar nas linhas o texto digitado na `textbox1` independente da ordem que elas estejam nas colunas, por exemplo:

Digitando "Baby" eu acho duas linhas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se eu digitar "Branca" que é uma cor, na frente de "Baby" sem o "look", o filtro nao acha nada. Olhem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o comando que eu uso para filtrar:

```
 Private Sub BuscaProduto()

    frm_gerar_pedido.filtro_descricao.Filter =
        "[cat_produto] Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" _
        & "or [descricao_produto] Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" _
        & "or [formato] Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" _
        & "or [cor] Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" _
        & "or [tamanho] Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'" _
        & "or [manga] Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
End Sub
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Se filtrar por "Baby Branca", não estará filtrando 2 palavras distintas "Baby" e "Branca", estará procurando em cada coluna algo que contenha "Baby Branca" na célula.

Comment: Qual o objetivo da pesquisa "*baby branca*"? Aparecer na mesma as duas linhas porque existem colunas que têm a palavra "*baby*" e "*branca*", ou apenas a 1ª porque é a **única** que tem duas colunas com "*baby*" e "*branca*"?

Answer (score 3):

Vc tem que fazer um laço para recorrer às colunas fazer o filtro e usar um `If/Else` para determinar o número de linhas retornado no `DataGrid` se for igual a zero passa pro próximo se for maior então exibe no `DataGrid` e passa pra próxima coluna.

Pense no algoritmo e escreva seu código, se escrever o código para vc não estarei te ajudando. 
Vc pode usar o `DataGridViewCell` ou `DataGridViewColumn` para recorrer às colunas no `foreach`.

E para obter o número de linhas é `DataGridView.Rows.Count` eu usaria um `DataTable` para armazenar as linhas pesquisadas e depois passaria o `DataTable` para o `DataGridView.DataSource`.

Mas se eu fosse vc colocaria um `ComboBox` com o nome das colunas para o usuário escolher em qual coluna fazer o filtro que ficaria bem mais fácil e simples.